# Error creating bean with name '/sbhupload' defined in class path resource - Junit

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

Getting the below error when I tried to integerate with junit in my existing spring project.

```
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name '/sbhupload' defined in class path
> resource [com/scb/test/base/CAD_ApplicationContext_Test.xml]:
> Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

Comment: The interesting part follows. What is the exception in the initializer.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.struts.util.MessageResources.getMessageResources(MessageResources.java:577)
 at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.<clinit>(DispatchAction.java:153)
 ... 40 more

Answer (score 0):

You seem to miss the addressed message resources on your classpath. As you provided no code, nothing more can be said.

MessageResources are text and i18n translations addressed through the struts framework, possibly jsp tags.

These are usually files with `foo_<locale_country>.properties`